# Calling an activity from a fragment - activity doesn't run

Tags: android, android-fragments

New to Android so bear with me.

I have a fragment (DirectionsFragment) that calls an Activity to get some data from Yelp (YelpActivity).

When I run the YelpActivity itself, without calling it from DirectionsFragment, it runs succesfully (displays the received information, prints out appropriate log messages, etc.).

However, when I create YelpActivity from the fragment, nothing happens - no log messages, no retrieved information.
Here's how I create the YelpActivity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        YelpActivity ya = new YelpActivity();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity is started by `startActivtiy(intent)`. But you have

```
YelpActivity ya = new YelpActivity();
```

Should not create an instance of Activity class.

Use

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivtiy(),YealpActivtiy.class);
```

Make sure you have declared the activity in manifest file

Comment: I see. If I want the Yelp code to run in the background, should I create an activity? Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @General_Twyckenham to run a background task why do you need activity. use thread or asynctask. Pls be clear you question says activity

Comment: I do apologize for the lack of clarity. I'm pretty new to Android dev, and was unclear about the distinction between a thread and an activity. Thanks for your help

Comment: background task use thread or asynctask no need fro another activity

Comment: Thanks, will do. I'll accept your answer when SO let's me (~8 minutes)

Comment: @General_Twyckenham depending on what you are doing, you may also want to look at [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)